Noise texture to control scatter density in geo nodes
I'm trying to control the density of a scatter with a noise texture.
Somehow it doesn't work. Doesn't matter which noise scale I use.



(Using Blender 3.6.8)
It seems the Density value per face must be captured before the Distribute Points on Faces node:

Resources: 

Ah I see thank you very much! I couldn't figure it out

Apparently the grid or other mesh also needs an higher resolution than the bare minimum because it works differently from the shader editor.


In the Shader Editor, texture value is interpolated at points (pixels ?) inside faces. So you get many values per face. In your case with GN, texture value is interpolated per face. So you get only one value per face. By increasing the grid resolution in GN, you are making smaller and smaller faces, until you get very few pixels (?) per face. This is why you recover what seems the Shader Editor behaviour.

That makes sense, thanks for the explaination :)
